# Remove Done bar on IQKeyboardManagerSwift

Tags: ios, swift

Im new to this lIbrary and to swift and im looking to remove this "Done" grey bar. How can I go about doing this? And other input would be of great help.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?


    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        //Configures all of Firebase
        FIRApp.configure()

        //Configure Key Board manager from Library (IQKEYboardManagerSwift)
        IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enable = true

        //Tab Bar Appearnece
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white



        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In your AppDelegate you can add:

```
IQKeyboardManager.sharedManager().enableAutoToolbar = false
```

to disable the toolbar.

Also under *`MARK: IQToolbar handling`* you'll find properties which might help you customize the toolbar the way you want.

Don't forget to explore the IQKeyboardManager.swift class a bit ;]

Comment: Thank you. You are much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In Latest swift:

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

```
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift
```

then

```
IQKeyboardManager.shared.enableAutoToolbar = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, if you want to disable it for a specific textfield you can use

Swift 4.2+:

```swift
   self.textfield.inputAccessoryView = UIView()
```

Objective-C:

```objectivec
   self.textField.inputAccessoryView = [[UIView alloc] init];
```

More on that [here](https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQKeyboardManager/wiki/Manual-Management)